# Boost Spirit synthesised attribute confusion

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse input which has either a plus or minus character, followed by an X or Y character, followed by an unsigned integer.

```
(char_('+') | char_('-')) >> char_("xyXY") >> uint_
```

According to my reading of the docs, the synthesised attribute for this would be `tuple<vector<char>,unsigned int>` because the alternative parser `(char | char)` would be of type `char`, the `char >> char("xyXY")` would be `vector<char>`, and the `vector<char> >> uint_` would be a tuple of the types, so `tuple<vector<char>,unsigned int>`. This fails to compile

```
qi\detail\assign_to.hpp(152) : error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const char' to 'boost::tuples::tuple<T0,T1>'
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string input("-Y 512");
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;
    Iterator first = input.begin();
    Iterator last = input.end();
    boost::tuple<std::vector<char>,unsigned int> output;
    bool result = phrase_parse(first,last,(char_('+') | char_('-')) >> char_("xyXY") >> uint_,ascii::space,output);
    if(result && first == last)
        std::cout << "sign=" << boost::get<0>(output)[0] << ", xy=" << boost::get<0>(output)[1] << ", size=" << boost::get<1>(output) << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "Parse error\n";
}
```

I then tried `tuple<char,char,unsigned int>` as the attribute type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string input("-Y 512");
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;
    Iterator first = input.begin();
    Iterator last = input.end();
    boost::tuple<char,char,unsigned int> output;
    bool result = phrase_parse(first,last,(char_('+') | char_('-')) >> char_("xyXY") >> uint_,ascii::space,output);
    if(result && first == last)
        std::cout << "sign=" << boost::get<0>(output) << ", xy=" << boost::get<1>(output) << ", size=" << boost::get<2>(output) << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "Parse error\n";
}
```

This compiles but the output is incorrect. The first token of the input is parsed correctly, but the subsequent tokens aren't:

```
sign=-, xy= , size=0
```

I also tried `as_string[]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string input("-Y 512");
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;
    Iterator first = input.begin();
    Iterator last = input.end();
    boost::tuple<std::string,unsigned int> output;
    bool result = phrase_parse(first,last,as_string[(char_('+') | char_('-')) >> char_("xyXY")] >> uint_,ascii::space,output);
    if(result && first == last)
        std::cout << "sign=" << boost::get<0>(output)[0] << ", xy=" << boost::get<0>(output)[1] << ", size=" << boost::get<1>(output) << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "Parse error\n";
}
```

This improved things as the x/y token got parsed, but not the third integer token:

```
sign=-, xy=Y, size=0
```

Please show me where I'm going wrong.

*I'm using Spirit version 2.5.2 (from Boost 1.58.0) and Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Spirit` library docs recommend to use `Fusion tuple`. I think I saw somewhere (can't find it now) that Boost `tuple` may not be fully compatible with `Spirit` library.

Here is your fixed example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string input("-Y 512");
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;
    Iterator first = input.begin();
    Iterator last = input.end();

    boost::fusion::tuple<char, char, unsigned int> output;
    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, (qi::char_('+') | qi::char_('-')) >> qi::char_("xyXY") >> qi::uint_, qi::ascii::space, output);
    if (result && first == last)
        std::cout << "sign=" << boost::fusion::get<0>(output) << ", xy=" << boost::fusion::get<1>(output) << ", size=" << boost::fusion::get<2>(output) << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "Parse error\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`sign=-, xy=Y, size=512`

**Update:** Actually I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692569/4899330) that it's possible to use `boost::tuple` but different header needs to be included: `#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>`.